# Viewer/parser to show all the Javascript in a web page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-extensions

I am looking for a tool (preferably a plugin to Firefox) that will show and parse all the JS in a page as I browse.

UPDATE:

Most tools focus on the HTML parser.
I need good js parsing e.g. list of all JS functions in a webpage, with includes...

Try Firebug on this link http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js and you get sore eyes.

Comment: Would this be firebug? https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-TW/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: See update about. In short, i need more powerful js parsing

Comment: you may try http://firerainbow.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 4):

Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools is probably your best bet.

Chrome Developer Tools has a ["pretty print" feature](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&t=29m49s) that allows you to deobfuscate JavaScript code, making it easier to read. You can get the same feature in Firebug by installing the [JavaScript Deminifier extension](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Javascript_Deminifier), or you can just use [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) if you want to deobfuscate an individual JavaScript file.

When debugging in either Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, you can see a list of all JavaScript variables and functions available within the local or global scope. In Chrome, you can even edit the JavaScript dynamically. Last year's [Google I/O presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg) explains how to use Chrome to debug JavaScript.

If your end goal is to read through or understand a piece of JavaScript, something like JSBeautifier should suffice, perhaps in addition to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you want to do some testing. Otherwise, if your goal is to understand JavaScript within the context of a website, using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to set breakpoints and step through the JavaScript code should work well. I personally use both when perusing JavaScript files in web apps, and they both have suited my needs just fine.